# installing NodeJS v14.18.0 and npm 6.14.15 on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, installation, apt

I know there are a lot of questions and solutions regarding node js installations but I am still going to ask this since no solution worked for me and I need to solve this so bad.

I have tried many solutions on StackOverflow but I am still not able to install node js version 14.18.0 and npm 6.14.15.

Here is one of the options I tried but it says that it can't find the version.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js-legacy

sudo apt-get update

apt install nodejs=14.18.0-1chl1~precise1
```

please share if there is a solution that works.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I just edited the post and added what I tried. it only says that it can't find the nodejs version.

Comment: What command did you write to install? Was it `sudo apt install nodejs` or another?

Comment: `sudo apt install nodejs` installs the current version. I have added the command that I used to mention the version.

Comment: Make sure that you have already installed `npm`.

Comment: I don't think I can be able to install npm before node. unless there is a specific code for that.

Comment: It can be helpful for you https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/installation-of-node-js-on-linux/amp/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @SunderamDubey, I have tried that as well. However, it installs the latest versions, not the versions that I mentioned above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243474/discussion-between-egidius-and-sunderam-dubey).

Comment: I'd suggest removing the node version you installed via `apt` and use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) instead ...

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```